# Is it possible to deploy a Java Servlet to GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, servlets

Is it possible to deploy a Java Servlet to GAE, or does the server need to be hosted elsewhere?

Comment: Your question is confusing. GAE is entirely centered around servlets.

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: **Yes**

**Slightly longer answer:**

App Engine uses the Jetty servlet container to host applications and supports the Java Servlet API version 2.4. Keep in mind though that there are quite a few restrictions in place that you have to respect ([source](http://www.vogella.de/articles/GoogleAppEngineJava/article.html)):

- App Engine runs a version of Java 6 but does not provide all Java classes, for example Swing and most AWT classes are not supported.
- You cannot use Threads or frameworks which use Threads.
- You may not write to the filesystem.
- You may only read files which are part of your application.
- Certain "java.lang.System" actions, e.g. gc() or exit() will do nothing.
- You can not call JNI code.
- Reflection is possible for your own classes and standard Java classes, but your cannot use reflection to access other classes outside your application.
- A servlet must reply within 30 seconds or a `com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException` is thrown.
- See [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html) for the Java classes that are white-listed.

Be sure to also read up on [The Sandbox](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Sandbox) to see examples of what will and will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* deploy a basic servlet to GAE, but there are additional things you need to do for GAE to accept it.

I would *highly* recommend a quick web search on the topic. You will find that there are *tons* of resources for this, including the documentation at the GAE site itself.

Comment: all i found were things about "backends" - is that the GAE version of the servlet, or am i mistaken? Also, would i have to use jsps?

Comment: Just like Java is all about abstractions, GAE has a particular structure that you have to adhere to.  Since you have to read through all of that to use GAE, please do so as your questions will be answered easily.  It is pretty painless to go from a servlet to GAE.