# Can .dll files be loaded in app engine Java with JNA?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, dll, jna

Can JNA be used to load .dll files on App engine ? If Yes, how can I set the system properties so that the .dll files can be loaded ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from GAE documentation:

"An app also cannot use JNI or other native code. The JVM can execute any Java bytecode that operates within the sandbox restrictions."

Take a look at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview.html

Alternatives might be: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/955462616d229b3e?pli=1

Comment: Also, it wouldn't be a dll anyway - Google run Linux on their servers.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you cannot use JNA in conjunction with App Engine (and thus no `.dll` files can be loaded). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8976747/1101070) answer for a brief overview of what you can and cannot run on App Engine.