# GAE and common servlet controller

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976611/is-it-possible-to-deploy-a-java-servlet-to-gae) question and it says it is possible to deploy a common servlet on GAE; 
OK... But what about the servlet controller in this case? Is it possible to make to access the common servlet with deployed app only?

I mean how to make servlet being accessible with its native web app only?

To be more clear...

Currently I am using code like `GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+"myservletmapping?id=N"` to get servlet; but there is a question like

- A) Shall I be able access my servlet after GAE deploy in the said way?
- B) How to make it accessable with my GWT app only (the app where the
  servlet is integrated) ?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to have HttpServlet(s) in my GWT app; And make the servlets being accessible with the GWT app only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, GAE supports servlets; You can deploy servlets on GAE and call them; Please watch [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating) for more details